# Must I wait to resubmit my return on Free File Fillable Forms?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, free-file-fillable-forms

I used [Free File Fillable Forms](https://www.freefilefillableforms.com/#/fd) to submit my income tax return. After submitting your return you are supposed to hear back from the IRS within 24-48 hrs as to whether they accepted the return. There are a whole list of errors that they will catch and reject your return.

After I submitted I noticed that I forgot to include SSNs for my dependents. I assume that they will catch my error and reject my return. Then I’ll have to resubmit. Meanwhile, Tax Day is fast approaching. Do I have to wait for them to reject my return? Or can I just fix the error and submit again? (Preferably electronically.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to wait for them to reject and follow the instructions on how to resubmit. In some cases, if e-file got rejected, you'll have to paper-file the fixed one.

If you're rejected, the submission deadline [gets extended by a few days](http://support.cch.com/kb/solution.aspx/sw2662), so as long as you resubmit on time, you're OK.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the rejection came very quickly so it was not painful to wait and I was still able to resubmit before the deadline.